# An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateChangeSet operation ..... is in ROLLBACK_COMPLETE state and can not be updated

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I understand why AWS leaves a stack if a deploy fails so you can see the error.

But is there a force switch so i can redeploy and have aws delete the stack for me? Otherwise I have to delete it myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure how you are creating CFT stack but if you are using CLI, you can specify `--on-failure DELETE` option which will delete the stack if the deployment fails.

Comment: yeah but like i said it remains so you can look at the error. Id prefer a force switch that deletes it because then I can choose to look at the error if i want or just re-run the command

Comment: There is no `force` switch kind of a thing but if you are using CLI then try to `delete` the stack and then `create` it.

Comment: thats what i do now. just wasn't sure if this was really the only way- i guess so :(

Comment: `Unknown options: --on-failure`

Answer (score 1):

This has happened once in a Buildkite pipeline, and after manually deleting the stack (Status: DELETE_COMPLETE) was able to re-create/update via the pipeline.